# Why is the highest NUMERIC precision in most RDBMS 38?

Tags: sql, history, rdbms

SQL-92 says:

```
         16)For the <exact numeric type>s DECIMAL and NUMERIC:

            a) The maximum value of <precision> is implementation-defined.
              <precision> shall not be greater than this value.
```

And yet it's 38 in Oracle, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Snowflake, Teradata. Only MySQL and DB2 are different, allowing up to 65 and 31 significant digits respectively. I guess it's because a 128 bits integer can guarantee 38 decimal digits of precision, but how did almost everyone agree on using a 128 bits integer for storing the mantissa?

Comment: That 128 bit to 38 decimals precision makes perfect sense. Popular binary types are 8, 16, 32, 64 and 128 bits long. I do not know of practical implementations for 256 and up so folks choosing the maximum for representing high precision numbers is to be expected and hardly a coincidence. The other numbers do raise some interesting questions though. 65 may map to 192 bits and 31 possibly to 80. Wikipedia has a convenient page related to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two .

Comment: There's decimal128, which supports 34 significant digits. I know it's much newer than most of these systems, but it allows the whole number to fit into 128 bits, not just the mantissa.